# Snakemake don't execute bash command

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to run a little pipeline in Snakemake for a software to filter good reads in files from a RNA-seq.

This is my code:

```
SAMPLES = ['ZN21_S1', 'ZN22_S2','ZN27_S3', 'ZN28_S4', 'ZN29_S5' ,'ZN30_S6']
rule all:
    input:
        expand("SVA-{sample}_L001_R{read_no}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES, read_no=['1', '2'])
rule fastp:
    input:
        reads1="SVA-{sample}_L001_R1.fastq.gz",
        reads2="SVA-{sample}_L001_R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        reads1out="out/SVA-{sample}_L001_R1.fastq.gz.good",
        reads2out="out/SVA-{sample}_L001_R2.fastq.gz.good"
    shell:
        "fastp -i {input.reads1} -I {input.reads2} -o {output.reads1out} -O {output.reads2out}"
```

All samples (in symbolic link) are in the same folder and I only got the message "Nothing to be done".
What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, target files in `rule all` are supposed to match with `rule fastp`'s output files, instead of its input files in your current setup.  As per your code, target files in `rule all` already exist and hence the message `Nothing to be done` when executing it.

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("out/SVA-{sample}_L001_R{read_no}.fastq.gz.good", sample=SAMPLES, read_no=['1', '2'])
```

Comment: I tried that, JeeYem, but I got this error:
MissingInputException in line 2 of /work/users/leboralli/iPSZika/fastp/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
out/SVA-ZN29_S5_L001_R1.fastq.gz
...

Comment: @LeandroBoralli Sounds like input files `SVA-ZN29_S5_L001_R1.fastq.gz` and `SVA-ZN29_S5_L001_R2.fastq.gz` corresponding to sample `ZN29_S5` are not present in the working directory. Assuming your Snakefile is located in the working directory, make sure above mentioned input files are present in that same directory.

Comment: I understood what I'm missing. Thank you for your help @JeeYem.